# Azure Function publish reduce SCM Environment setting timout duration

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I try to publish my project to an azure function I sometimes encounter the following error:

```
~$ func azure functionapp publish <function_app_name> --python
Getting site publishing info...
Starting the function app deployment...
Updating Application Settings for Remote build...
Timed out waiting for SCM to update the Environment Settings
```

This error is expected and is related to some of the pipelines I'm working with.

The issue is that this timeout sometimes takes up to ~6-8 minutes. I have searched in both the azure portal and in the `functionapp publish` command for ways to reduce this timeout duration to ~2 minutes, but can't seem to find it. Is there any way to change this parameter?

Comment: can you please share your function code

Comment: please refer https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1863

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin This issue seems to persist over multiple projects, so my issue is not specific to the code. I also read through the github issue. It is very related but it regards automatically retrying the operation, not reducing the time it takes before erroring on the SCM Env Settings

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnússon You can make use of premium Function plan or dedicated function plan to increase the timeout. Also check if Always On feature is enabled in your Function app

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I'm already using the premium function plan and the issue I'm experiencing is that the default timeout is too large. The Always On feature is also enabled on the app. I believe the timeout duration is hardcoded to 300 sec in azure-functions-core-tools

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnússon Can you check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006089/azure-function-timeout ?Try to set the timeout value in hosts.json and see?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai would the `functionTimeout` parameter not also set the timeout of the whole application to this low number I want to set the SCM timeout to?

Comment: For SCM timeout try to set this setting in your function app configuration or environment variables - SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT Reference- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#build-automation and also check if you are using correct connection string to your storage account, As per this MS Q & A thread on the same error code as yours which got resolved after adding correct connection string- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/592588/function-app-publish-timed-out-waiting-for-scm-to

Comment: Resolved this issue myself. The Application Setting WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING contained an outdated storage account key. According to the [**MS Q & A l**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/592588/function-app-publish-timed-out-waiting-for-scm-to)ink

Comment: Did above solution helped?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I tried to set the `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT=15` in the app settings but the `publish` command is still hanging on the `Updating Application Settings for Remote build...` step. When I tested, it was still stuck on this for 305 seconds (pretty much exactly 5 minutes).

Comment: @SiddheshDesai from what I can tell this value is hardcoded to 300 seconds on [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/1a1ae9c79281dd44d68f2ddd0d35aab716f21f23/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/Actions/AzureActions/PublishFunctionAppAction.cs#L755) line

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnússon Refer this github issue it might resolve your issue -https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1863

Comment: It looks like a permission issue using owner or giving service principal direct access of contributor role to function app has resolved the issue for many

Comment: IF its a default setting of 300 seconds it cannot be changed, but the timeout issue can be resolved by changing the service connection with proper roles to your function app according to the github issue above

Comment: @SiddheshDesai ok then it seems for now there is no way to edit this timeout. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255498/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-steinn-hauser-magnusson).

Answer (score 1):

The Default SCM timeout cannot be changed, You can raise a github feature request [**here**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues) to change the timeout at the product level.

I tried deploying a Function app with the same command  in my Azure DevOps pipeline and it was successful, Refer below:-

***According to this github issue [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1863) changing the service principal role to Contributor or Owner at Function App, Resource Group or Subscription level has succeeded the Deployment. My service principal has a Owner role at the Subscription level, You can assign atleast contributor role to the service principal at resource group or function app level. Go through other comments in the same github issue***

**My Yaml script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      #!/bin/bash
      sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
      python -m venv funcenv
      source funcenv/bin/activate
      pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./siliconfunc432/requirements.txt --upgrade
      pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" --no-cache-dir cffi --upgrade
      curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
      sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
      sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-$(lsb_release -sc) $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools
      az login --service-principal -u <client-id> -p <client-secret> --tenant <tenant-id>
      az account set --subscription <subscription-id>
      
      
      func azure functionapp publish functionappname --python
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Local output with `az login` command where I logged in with user with Owner role-***

```bash
func azure functionapp publish siliconfunc54 --python
```

[image]

[image]